# Return records less than date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where 2 columns are called Month and Year and are both INT. I need to return all the records that are less than the date provided.

So if I pass the following parameters `@Month = 8` and `@Year = 2017`, I would like to return all records before August 2017. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
SELECT * FROM testTable
WHERE year <= @Year AND
      month < @Month
```

is my current SQL. This won't work if I need to display the record that is November 2014

Comment: you can add `case` statement for month. Like compare only if `year = @Year`

Comment: If at all possible you should not separate date parts like this. It means that you will constantly have to cram them back together into an actual date. The real problem there is it means that none of your queries will be SARGable. Storing data in the appropriate datatype will save you so much anguish.

Comment: @SeanLange I understand that 100%. Unfortunately, I did not design the database. I can't understand why we would ever need to store a date in separate columns. Just makes it difficult when we need to add logic to a simple query. Whether it be in the SP or in the code.

Comment: And I know that sometimes we are kind of stuck with a crappy design that somebody else put in place for us to inherit. Maybe you can add a computed column to the table? If you made it persisted you can even index it. If that is possible it would be a way better approach from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare them as dates. Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM testTable
WHERE  DATEFROMPARTS(year, month, 1) <= DATEFROMPARTS(@Year, @Month, 1)
```

Comment: This helped a ton! Thank you so much. I am not the best in SQL so this helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Pass The Parameter as Date. Like

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATE = '08-01-2014'
```

Now you can go for either of the below

```
SELECT
  *
  FROM YourTable
     WHERE CAST(ConCAT([Monnth],'-01-',[Year]) AS DATE) = @MyDate
```

Or

```
SELECT
   *
   FROM YourTable
      WHERE [Year] = YEAR(@MyDate)
            AND [Month] = MONTH(@MyDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEPART function of SQL Server

```
 SELECT * FROM testTable
 WHERE YEAR<= DATEPART(yy,yourdate) AND
 MONTH < DATEPART(mm,yourdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to convert data types  and query further.

```
    DECLARE @testtable TABLE (id INT identity(1, 1), name VARCHAR(100), year INT, month INT)

INSERT INTO @testtable (name, year, month)
SELECT 'me', '2014', 10

UNION

SELECT 'you', '2017', 08

UNION

SELECT 'us', '2015', 10

UNION

SELECT 'Him', '2017', 10

UNION

SELECT 'Her', '2018', 1

SELECT *
FROM @testtable
WHERE CONCAT (year, '-', right('00' + cast(Month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2), '-', '01') 
< = '2017-08-01'
```